# Failed to build AOSP [run_soong_ui] Error 1

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to compile android version 7.1.2 master branch. I already set up following the instructions from source.android.com. When I run `make -j8` I got this error and also an error message from jack-server which I think maybe is related to the build error. The last messages of the verbose output:

> [ 41% 1715/4084] Ensuring Jack server is installed and started
>   FAILED: setup-jack-server 
>   /bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server 
> prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation\" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0 ) &&
>  (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar 4.11.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.31.CANDIDATE.jar 4.31.CANDIDATE || exit 47 )"
>   Jack server already installed in "/home/fabio/.jack-server"
>   Communication error with Jack server (28), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
>   Communication error with Jack server 28. Try 'jack-diagnose'
>   Communication error with Jack server 28. Try 'jack-diagnose'
>   [ 42% 1719/4084] Docs droiddoc: out/target/common/docs/api-stubs
>   DroidDoc took 687 sec. to write docs to out/target/common/docs/api-stubs
>   [ 42% 1720/4084] Docs droiddoc: out/target/common/docs/test-api-stubs
>   DroidDoc took 687 sec. to write docs to out/target/common/docs/test-api-stubs
>   [ 42% 1721/4084] Docs droiddoc: out/target/common/docs/system-api-stubs
>   DroidDoc took 705 sec. to write docs to out/target/common/docs/system-api-stubs
>   [ 42% 1722/4084] //external/llvm:libLLVM link libLLVM.so
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>   16:58:24 ninja failed with: exit status 1
>   build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
>   make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing heap size with java option '-Xmx'