# Android Build Error: make: *** [build/core/main.mk:21: run_soong_ui] Error 1

Tags: java, android, linux, build, android-source

I am trying to build AOSP from source for the Nexus 6P and encountering the following error.  This issue started happening with branch android-8.0.0_r17 (OPR5.170623.007) and has continued in branch android-8.0.0_r31 (OPR5.170623.011).  Branches prior to *_r17 did not have this issue for me.

```
[ 85% 69912/81560] Building with...rmediates/with-local/classes.de
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
01:31:54 ninja failed with: exit status 1
make: *** [build/core/main.mk:21: run_soong_ui] Error 1
#### make failed to build some targets (42:12 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Similar questions have been asked before, but the [suggestion to increase the Java heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)([here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789978/failed-to-build-aosp-run-soong-ui-error-1)) did not work for me.  Nor did syncing the repo again, syncing repo with a single tread, or building with a single thread (in suspicion of running out of memory).  prebuilt/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison does exist (as [suggested here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/KSOvjAIzRwA) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/1f7zaa3My8E)).  The [question has also been unanswered on XDA Developers for branch *_12](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/make-runsoongui-error-1-making-android-t3681080).

My base system is Arch Linux (4.13.11-1-hardened), virtualenv in place (to use Python2 as python), and JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk. 
 I'm out of ideas and would really like to continue developing my Android projects.  Any suggestions?